# I am trying to add class names to a list within a drawer to be able to call each button within the list separately

Tags: javascript, material-ui

```
 return (
        <Box
            sx={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                overflow: "hidden",
            }}
        >
            <Drawer
                variant="permanent"
                anchor="left"
                hideBackdrop
                sx={{
                    width: DRAWER_WIDTH,
                    flexShrink: 0,
                    ".MuiPaper-root": {
                        bgcolor: "info.main",
                        width: DRAWER_WIDTH,
                        position: "absolute",
                        height: "100%",
                    },
                }}
            >
                <List>
                    {Object.values(Types.InputMode).map((v) => (
                        <Fragment key={v}> 
                    
                            <ListItem
                                button
                                onClick={() => setView(v)}
                                
                                sx={{ bgcolor: v === view ? "action.selected" : undefined }}
                            >
                                {v}
                            </ListItem>
                        </Fragment>
                    ))}
                </List>
            </Drawer>
            <Route path={path + Types.InputRoutes[Types.InputMode.Create]}>
                <CreateProject />
            </Route>
            <Route path={path + Types.InputRoutes[Types.InputMode.Open]}>
                <OpenProject />
            </Route>
            <Route path={path + Types.InputRoutes[Types.InputMode.Import]}>
                <ImportProject />
            </Route>
        </Box>
    );
```

I am trying to add class names to a list within a drawer to be able to call each button within the list separately. I am struggling on where I can add classNames for these 3 buttons. Any help would be appreciated.

[3 buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MePZo.png)

Comment: You can directly add the `className` inside the `ListItem`. Add `className={<Your Value Here>}`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I really appreciate it. 

I have tried that but I can only do one className. I need to do 3 classNames.

Comment: Do you want to do 3 classNames at once or depending on some variable?

Comment: I have a JSON file that I am using to call classNames. I need have each one on the list separate so I can call them one at a time.

Comment: Where do you get the Types from? You could add the class value there. Like `Types.InputMode.Create.clazzName = 'create-element-class-name'` and then use it inside `map` function. BTW, you don't need a Fragment in the List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your `Types.InputMode` object looks like, but you can use simple JavaScript insider your rendering function.

```
    Object.values(Types.InputMode).map((v) => {

        const getClassName = function (value) {
            if (value === "foo") {
                return 'bar';
            }
            return 'default';
        }

        const className = getClassName(v);
        return (<Fragment key={v}>

            <ListItem button onClick={() => setView(v)}
                className={className}
                sx={{ bgcolor: v === view ? "action.selected" : undefined }}
            >
                {v}
            </ListItem>
        </Fragment>)
    })
```

You can outsource the rendering function for better code, but I hope this will help you.

Comment: You're welcome. Thats why we're all here ;)